# Retina images in IE 8 not scaled properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm sure there's some incompatible property I'm using here, just can't figure out which. This website looks fine on modern browsers, but in IE 8 some of the retina images I'm using (like especially the header image) are twice as big as I'm declaring them to be in css. I originally had the widths set to `inherit` and I thought that was the issue, but after changing them to a fixed pixel width they still don't scale down. What's wrong?

Also, if this helps identify the problem, for the retina images that do scale properly (like the thumbnails on the "collection" page) when I use developer tools in IE 8 I can see their `width`. However for the header image and others, I cannot. It's like it isn't seeing the width property I've declared.

The website: 
http://seventhheavenvintage.com/preview/

and the collection page which has retina images that work: http://seventhheavenvintage.com/preview/collection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max-width: 100%;
```

did the trick.